# Placing a LocalDB Database into AppData via Installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, localdb, sql-server-2012-express

I developed an application (WinForm app built with VS2012) that uses SQL Server LocalDB.

I create the .exe file for the application and the database to install it on another machine using the Visual Studio 2012 tools (InstallShield Limited Edition or ClickOnce).  The application installs on another machine, but when I launch it I receive this error message:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file
>   C:\Users\%nom_utilisateur%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Data\blabla\blabla\Data\Devessai.mdf
>   failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot
>   be opened, or it is located on a UNC share.

Now when I copy the database to the path specified in the error message then application works perfectly.

How can I can put the database directly into the AppData folder via the application installer?

this is app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  

<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="mdf_projet.Properties.Settings.DevEssaiConnectionString" 
              connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DevEssai.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" 
              providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This problem is not related to your application config, but to your ClickOnce deployment.

Comment: how i can solve this problem ?

Comment: You mention both ClickOnce and InstallShield Limited Edition, which one are you using?  This are very different installer build tools.

Comment: Also, how is this database created?  Is it pre-generated and being deployed, or is it being provisioned by your code?

Comment: when i use clickonce the message d'error is: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\%nom_utilisateur%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Data\blabla\blabla\Data\Devess‌​ai.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on a UNC share. when i use installshield the same message d'error but the path is of the .exe file C:\prgramme_file\application\ .  @ JNYRanger

Comment: the database is created with sql server after i import it as a localdb in VS2012 @ JNYRanger

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem in click once in publish -> file Application -> selects the database and change publish status of the database to become data file.